# Incorrect number of parameters bound to PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a method verifyCredentials in a class that's used to verify user credentials. I'm rewriting it to make use of PHP's PDO instead of DBMS dependant mysqli-statements. I'm having trouble with getting parameters bound to my prepared query.

PDO always throws the warning

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in [file] on line [line]

I'm clearly missing something here, but I can't figure out what for the life of me.

Code snippet, everything in caps except DBH and STH are defined by an external constants.php file:

```
class FancyClass{
function __construct(){
    try{
        $this->DBH=
            new PDO(PDO_DRIVER.':host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_DB,
                    DB_USER, DB_PWD);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
    $this->queryGetPwdForUser="select :userIdCol , :pwdCol from :usersTable where :aliasCol = ':alias' limit 1"
}

function __destruct(){
    $this->DBH=null;
}

function verifyCredentials($alias,$pwd){
    $STH=$this->DBH->prepare($this->queryGetPwdForUser);
    $STH->bindParam(':userIdCol',$userIdCol);
    $STH->bindParam(':pwdCol',$pwdCol);
    $STH->bindParam(':usersTable',$usersTable);
    $STH->bindParam(':aliasCol',$aliasCol);
    $STH->bindParam(':alias',$alias);
    $userIdCol=DB_COLUMN_USERID;
    $pwdCol=DB_COLUMN_USERPWD;
    $usersTable=DB_TABLE_USERS;
    $aliasCol=DB_COLUMN_USERALIAS;
    $STH->execute();
    $result=$STH->fetch();

    if($result==false) return false;
    $hasher = new PasswordHash(50,false);
    if($hasher->CheckPassword($pwd,$result[DB_COLUMN_USERPWD]))
        return $result[DB_COLUMN_USERID];
    else
        return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Even when you've fixed it like `Let me see` suggests below, you can't bind mysql keywords, tables or columns to placeholders using prepared statements. You first have to create a SQL string query like so `$sql = "SELECT $userIdCol,$pwdCol FROM $usersTable WHERE $aliasCol = :alias";` and in this case you will only be able to bind the `:alias` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify what needs to be done, even though fixing the `':alias'` quotes suggested before, MySQL keywords (like SELECT, INSERT), table names and column names can't be bound through placeholders using prepared statements. In order to dynamically create a MySQL query, you have to replace these values in some other way.

I noticed you're predefining the SQL queries already, so using something like `str_replace` or maybe define a general method which may replace these placeholder with values like so:

```
$sql = str_replace(array(
  ':userIdCol',
  ':pwdCol',
  ':usersTable',
  ':aliasCol'
), array(
  $userIdCol,
  $pwdCol,
  $usersTable,
  $aliasCol
), $this->queryGetPwdForUser);
```

Obviously the approach for the prepared statement in this case

```
$STH=$this->DBH->prepare($sql);
$STH->bindParam(':alias',$alias);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm relatively new to PHP. The `str_replace` is one of those things I don't think about yet.

Comment: Be sure to escape the input if the values are not controlled by you, for `PDO` this will be `PDO::quote($userIdCol)` etc. See [PDO::quote](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) and for `mysqli` [real_esacpe_string](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Well, I've upvoted it again for you ;) Thanks again for your help. The class in the OP has been rewritten succesfully. BTW: when using PDO::prepare, you don't need to use PDO::quote anymore, prepared statements have bound parameters escaped automagically ;)

Comment: It's true PDO escapes bound parameters automatically, you can use `PDO::quote` when generating a SQL string, in the example, e.g. when `$aliasCol` would be a value from an external source, let's say `$_POST`. It's just one of many precautions to prevent SQL injection of any kind.